# WebdriverIO: Have waitForDisplayed() not fail a test if it returns false

Tags: appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I'm using WebdriverIO and Appium in Javascript to test Android/iOS apps.

I have a welcome screen that sometimes shows up after a loading screen. The following code is what I'm using at the moment to skip past the welcome screen.

```
if(welcomeScreenTitle.waitForDisplayed()){
   skipWelcomeScreenButton.click();
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that if the waitForDisplayed() times out (meaning that the screen hasn't showed up this time), it fails the test. Is there a way that I can do this?

I have tried using

```
browser.wait(10000);
if(welcomeScreenTitle.isDisplayed()){
   skipWelcomeScreenButton.click();
}
```

But the loading screen time is different depending on the speed of the connection (so might be much longer), and if the welcome screen shows up before 10 seconds, I don't want to wait the full 10 seconds (since most of the time it does show up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier way of doing this is adding a try catch block around your code so that you can suppress the error thrown and continue the execution.

```
try {
browser.waitForDisaplyed(10000);
if(welcomeScreenTitle.isDisplayed()){
   skipWelcomeScreenButton.click();
}
} catch (error) {
console.log('Welcomescreen is not displayed.')
}
```